# "gms 23.34.14" canot get gms API by original android application

Tags: android, kotlin, google-chrome

Occured;
on the application, it is displayed that "17:API is not available on this device", and nearby system doesn't work.

Log from the device;

```
Failed to start discovery.
                                                                                              
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
                                                                                                
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zad.zad(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaE(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:7)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaD(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zar(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:24)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zai.onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:3)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzc.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:3)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:31)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
                                                                                                at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

device information:
1 jetfon s20i android9
2 lenovo m10hd2ndgen android10
3 lenovo yoga11 android12
4 lenovo B10HD2ndgen android 11

Expectation,
1 Solution of the problems we have.
2 The reason(s) of the problems.

Back ground;
we are developing Android application which includes nearby connection system via gms API to interconnect among some devices.